# Adding a new Kernel Call in Minix 3

Tags: makefile, kernel, minix

I have been trying to write a kernel call in Minix 3. I looked at the developer's guide and tried doing it, but came across an error in step 9.

```
# make /usr/src/${MACHINE_ARCH}
install ===> tools
install ===> lib
install ===> lib/csu
     install /usr/lib/crt0.o
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/lib/csu
*** Error code 1

Stop.
...
...
```

The error has been shown above. The link I followed is:
http://wiki.minix3.org/Releases/3.2.1/DevelopersGuide/NewKernelCall

Any idea why this error has come up? Or are there any other guides available in the internet? I haven't found any unfortunately.

Comment: Hello Madhura, were you able to get a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the environment variable `$MACHINE_ARCH` is set?

Try this on your prompt:

```
echo $MACHINE_ARCH
```